# There were concurrent policy changes. Please retry the whole read-modify-write with exponential backoff

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

POST METHOD URL

https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name:setIamPolicy

Request:

```
{
    "resource": "projects/project-name",
    "policy": {
        "bindings": [
            {
                "role": "roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin",
                "members": [
                    "user:test12345678@domain.com"
                ]
            }
         ],
        "etag": "BwWWja0YfJA=",
        "version": 3
     }
}
```

Response:

> {
>
> "error": {
>       "code": 409,
>       "message": "There were concurrent policy changes. Please retry the 
>                   whole read-modify-write with exponential backoff.",
>       "status": "ABORTED"   }
>
> }

Answer (score 4):

Documentation recommends using the read-modify-write pattern to update policy for a resource.

> Reading the current policy by calling getIamPolicy().
> Editing the returned policy, either by using a text editor or programmatically, to add or remove any desired members and their role grants.
> Writing the updated policy by calling setIamPolicy().

Looks like in your case the policy you're trying to set and the policy that is currently active on the resource have diverged. One of the ways this can happen is if you did:

1. getIamPolicy() > policy.json
2. addIamPolicyBinding() or removeIamPolicyBinding()
3. setIamPolicy() policy.json

The policy version on the resource after #2, is out of sync with what #3 is trying to set, and so it throws an exception. To confirm you can compare the etag field in the policy your strying to set with the etag currently on the resource. There should be a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

This means that more than one change was performed at the same time. You should try to perform only one request to change policies at the same time.

Implementing [Exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff) should help you with this error. It is as simple as handle your request retry with a time magnitude of `n+1 + random_number_milliseconds seconds and retry the request`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by removing

```
"etag": "BwWWja0YfJA=",
    "version": 3
```

from the template when using `gcloud projects set-iam-policy` command. It will ask you to overwrite the existing policy before committing the changes

Answer (score 0):

"etag": changes after every update.
Make sure you are using the most recent one from get command